# xarray combine dataarrays with multidimensional coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a dataset consisting of several "sources", each of which has a fixed number of "receivers" at (x, y) coordinates. For each source, the (x, y) coordinates of the receivers vary, but I was hoping to be able to work with them as a single dataset. As a minimal example, consider:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray

times = np.arange(100)
receivers = np.arange(30)

# Make the DataArray objects associated with each source
data_arrays = []
for i in range(10):
    # The (x, y) location of the receivers varies with source
    x = np.arange(i, i + receivers.size)
    y = np.arange(i, i + receivers.size) + 10

    da = xarray.DataArray(
        data=np.random.normal(size=(receivers.size, times.size)),
        dims=['receiver', 'time'],
        coords=dict(receiver=receivers, time=times),
        name=str(i),
    )

    # Create the actual coordinates associated with the receivers for this shot
    da = da.assign_coords(
        x=('receiver', x),
        y=('receiver', y)
    )
    data_arrays.append(da)

# Try to merge (same error with combine_by_coords)
dataset = xarray.merge(data_arrays)
```

However, this gives

```
MergeError: conflicting values for variable 'x' on objects to be combined. You can skip this check by specifying compat='override'.
```

I am really just looking for a useful container of these individual source DataArrays that lets me easily do things like get the data for a single source, for a single receiver across sources, for a single (x, y) coordinate, etc. Is there a way to merge dataarrays like this in xarray? Should I just write my own class for this container?